# How can I read an XML file properly into a collection when the XML has a specific root element name?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need to read this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Products>
<Product Name="Prod1">
  <Description>Desc1</Description >
  <Price>100</Price >
  <Stock>200</Stock>
</Product>
<Product Name="Prod2">
  <Description>Desc2</Description >
  <Price>50</Price >
  <Stock>400</Stock>
</Product>
</Products>
```

my idea was do something like this:

```
        public ICollection<ProductDTO> importtProducts()
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<ProductDTO>));
        TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"c:\importers\xmlimporter.xml");
        List<ProductDTO> prods;
        prods = (List<ProductDTO>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
        textReader.Close();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\importers\xmlimporter.xml");
        foreach (var prod in doc.Root.Descendants("Product").Distinct())
        {
            //work with the prod in here
        }
        return some prods..;
    }
```

but I'm having some problems with the root item, the xmlSerializer type.
does someone know which type should I use?
List, IList,  ICollection, IEnumerable....

thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you try creating a class called Products and have list of products as a property in it. Then directly deserialize into produts.

Comment: Hi Pratik, you suggestion worked ! thanks a lot !

Comment: Nice!!! Kevin.r beat me to it by seconds :)

Comment: hmmm, still having one problem, I can't read the property Name, works different because it is in the Product tag? any workaround for that ?

Comment: Add another property by that name and attribute called "Xmlattribute" rather than "xmlement". Simple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider creating one Products object with a List. You can then mark your objects as such:

```
public class Products
{
  [XmlElement("Product", Type = typeof(Product))]
  public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
  [XmlAttribute("Name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  [XmlElement("Description")]
  public string Description { get; set; }

  ...
}
```

This will generate to a Products class that has a list of type Product when using:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Products));
```

without specifying the type as a list

**UPDATE**
I added XmlAttribute("Name") to demonstrate the solution to the additional issue. @pratik-gaikwad relayed the solution before I did.

Comment: hmmm, still having one problem, I can't read the property Name, works different because it is in the Product tag? any workaround for that ?

Comment: Glad I could help. I've fought the XML battle a few times now and I feel for you.