# How do I rename the root node when serialising a List<object> to XML in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, attributes

I am serialising a List of US States into XML, and while I can control the names of most of the output elements with attributes, the root node is always called "ArrayOfStates". Is there a way to change this so it is just "States"?

Code:

```
    public class Program
    {
        [XmlArray("States")]
        public static List<State> States;

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            PopulateListOfStates();

            var xml = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<State>));
            xml.Serialize(new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\output.xml",Encoding.Default), States);
        }
    }

    public struct State
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name;

        [XmlArray("Neighbours")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Neighbour")]
        public List<string> Neighbours;
    }
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252"?>
<ArrayOfState xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <State Name="AL">
        <Neighbours>
            <Neighbour>FL</Neighbour>
            <Neighbour>GA</Neighbour>
            <Neighbour>MS</Neighbour>
            <Neighbour>TN</Neighbour>
        </Neighbours>
    </State>
    <State Name="FL">
        <Neighbours>
            <Neighbour>AL</Neighbour>
            <Neighbour>GA</Neighbour>
        </Neighbours>
    </State>
    <State Name="GA">
        <Neighbours>
            <Neighbour>AL</Neighbour>
            <Neighbour>FL</Neighbour>
            <Neighbour>NC</Neighbour>
            <Neighbour>SC</Neighbour>
            <Neighbour>TN</Neighbour>
        </Neighbours>
    </State>
    ...
</ArrayOfState>
```

As an aside, is it also possible to have the contents of the "Neighbour" elements as attributes of those elements (i.e. `<Neighbour name="XX"/>`)?

Comment: Create a wrapper root object as in this answer: [Read XML file properly c# linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391131/read-xml-file-properly-c-sharp-linq/40391198#40391198).  Or override the root element name as is shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624540/how-to-set-root-node-name-when-xmlserializing-an-array/1624569#1624569).  But if you use the second answer, you must cache the serializer in a static, as is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897145/memory-leak-using-streamreader-and-xmlserializer/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Serializable]
public class Worksheet
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "XML")]
    public class XML
    {
        [XmlArray("States")]
        public List<State> States { get; set; }
    }

    public class State
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("Neighbours")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Neighbour")]
        public List<Neighbour> Neighbours { get; set; }
    }

    public class Neighbour
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Worksheet.XML xml = PopulateListOfStates();

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Worksheet.XML));
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\output.xml", false))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, xml);
    }
}
```